# Hadoop - WordCount runs fine, but another example gets stuck

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I ran WordCount on a single node on my mac and it worked, so I made another MapReduce application and ran it, but it gets stuck at `map 10% reduce 0%` and sometimes at `map 0% reduce 0%`. The code of the application I made:

```
public class TemperatureMaximale {

    public static class TemperatureMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

        private Text city = new Text();
        private IntWritable temperature = new IntWritable();

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
            while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String line = itr.nextToken();
                String cityStr = line.split(",")[0];
                int temperatureInt = Integer.parseInt(line.split(",")[1].replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
                city.set(cityStr);
                temperature.set(temperatureInt);
                context.write(city, temperature);

            }
        }

    }

    public static class TemperatureReducer extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
        private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE; 
            for (IntWritable value : values) {
                maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, value.get());
            }
            result.set(maxValue);
            context.write(key, result);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "temperature");
        job.setJarByClass(TemperatureMaximale.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TemperatureMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(TemperatureReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(TemperatureReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
      }
}
```

I have no idea why this doesn't work since it's basically a copy of WordCount, I just do some different operations on map and reduce methods.

Example of the files I'm using as input:

```
Toronto, 20
Whitby, 25
New York, 22
Rome, 32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, it was just lack of memory to execute the job.
If you execute `hadoop job -list`, you can see the needed memory to execute the job. In my case it was 4096M. So I closed all other applications and all jobs ran fine.

You can also solve this configuring YARN in `mapred-site.xml` to allocate less memory to the job, as follows:

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
  <value>1024</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
  <value>1024</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx1638m</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx3278m</value>
</property>
```

`mapreduce.map.memory.mb` and `mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb` set the YARN container physical memory limits for your map and reduce processes respectively.

`mapreduce.map.java.opts` and `mapreduce.reduce.java.opts` set the JVM heap size for your map and reduce processes respectively. As a general rule, they should be 80% the size of the YARN physical memory settings.

Comment: Would be useful to others to show how you determined this